# Sound generation / synthesis with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, audio, synthesis

Is it possible to get python to generate a simple sound like a sine wave?

Is there a module available for this? If not, how would you go about creating your own?

Also, would you need some kind of host environment for python to run in in order to play sound, or can it be achieved just from making calls from the terminal?

If the answer is OS-dependent, I'm using a mac.

Comment: @hochl Well, how ironic it is that this is the first Google result returned after a day spent searching with different keywords...

Comment: I would check out [Pyo](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/index.html). [Here's](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/examples/02-controls/04-building-lfo.html) a good starting example.

Answer (score 46):

I was looking for the same thing, In the end, I wrote this code which is working fine.

```
import math        #import needed modules
import pyaudio     #sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio

PyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio     #initialize pyaudio

#See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Audio
BITRATE = 16000     #number of frames per second/frameset.      

FREQUENCY = 500     #Hz, waves per second, 261.63=C4-note.
LENGTH = 1     #seconds to play sound

BITRATE = max(BITRATE, FREQUENCY+100)

NUMBEROFFRAMES = int(BITRATE * LENGTH)
RESTFRAMES = NUMBEROFFRAMES % BITRATE
WAVEDATA = ''    

#generating wawes
for x in xrange(NUMBEROFFRAMES):
 WAVEDATA = WAVEDATA+chr(int(math.sin(x/((BITRATE/FREQUENCY)/math.pi))*127+128))    

for x in xrange(RESTFRAMES): 
 WAVEDATA = WAVEDATA+chr(128)

p = PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(1), 
                channels = 1, 
                rate = BITRATE, 
                output = True)

stream.write(WAVEDATA)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: This works, but generates a very loud "pop" at the end of playback.

Comment: Why do we need to cast these ints to ascii characters?

Comment: @Cerin That will be because the last sample it output was far from zero, and then your speakers suddenly returned to zero within a single sample, which produces a pretty significant noise. If you provide a couple samples at the end fading to zero, or make sure your wave has gone back to (close to) zero, you'll get a cleaner ending.

Comment: Can someone explain what `RESTRAMES` is and the purpose of appending `WAVEDATA + chr(128)`?

Comment: If I understand this correctly (and I'm not sure I do) then a frame is described by a single byte (not a bit) and `BITRATE` would be more properly named `BYTERATE`.

Comment: If `p = PyAudio()` returns `attempt to connect to server failed` you have to run `jack_server_control` first.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven WAVEDATA is string. WAVEDATA + chr(128) means "Add number represented as char to string WAVEDATA"

Comment: i cannot run this: complains about xrange:
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: @Cerin. The best solution to get rid of this click is to ramp the sine wave down with an exponentional function.

Answer (score 21):

I know I'm a little late to the game on this one, but this is a pretty fantastic python project for synthesis and audio composition: https://github.com/hecanjog/pippi

It's still actively being developed, but it's been going for a while.

Comment: 5 years into the future and it's still actively developed :O

Answer (score 7):

After wasting time on some uncompilable or non-existent projects, I discovered the python module [wavebender](https://github.com/zacharydenton/wavebender), which offers generation of single or multiple channels of sine, square and combined waves. The results can be written either to a wavefile or to `sys.stdout`, from where they can be interpreted directly by [aplay](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay) in real-time. Some useful examples are explained [here](http://zacharydenton.com/generate-audio-with-python/), and are included at the project's [github page](https://github.com/zacharydenton/wavebender).

Comment: Hi - I'm the author of pippi. It's been pre-release for quite a while but I'm working toward a stable 1.0 release. If you have time to submit a bug report with your problems on github I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, I'd love to look into it again and see if I can contribute something. Good to hear it's alive!

Comment: Unfortunately, wavebender still seems to be [non-functional and unmaintained.](https://github.com/zacharydenton/wavebender/issues/5)

Answer (score 6):

The Python In Music wiki page has not been terribly well-kept-up, but it's a good starting point.
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Answer (score 5):

I am working on a powerful synthesizer in python. I used custom functions to write directly to a .wav file. There are built in functions that can be used for this purpose. You will need to modify the .wav header to reflect the sample rate, bits per sample, number of channels, and duration of synthesis.

Here is an early version of a sin wave generator that outputs a list of values that after applying bytearray becomes suitable for writing to the data parameter of a wave file. **[edit]** A conversion function will need to transform the list into little endian hex values before applying the bytearray.  See the WAVE PCM soundfile format link below for details on the .wav specification.**[/edit]**

```
def sin_basic(freq, time=1, amp=1, phase=0, samplerate=44100, bitspersample=16):
    bytelist = []
    import math
    TwoPiDivSamplerate = 2*math.pi/samplerate
    increment = TwoPiDivSamplerate * freq
    incadd = phase*increment
    for i in range(int(samplerate*time)):
        if incadd > (2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1):
            incadd = (2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1) - (incadd - (2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1))
        elif incadd < -(2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1):
            incadd = -(2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1) + (-(2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1) - incadd)
        bytelist.append(int(round(amp*(2**(bitspersample - 1) - 1)*math.sin(incadd))))
        incadd += increment
    return bytelist
```

A newer version can use waveforms to modulate the frequency, amplitude, and phase of the waveform parameters. The data format makes it trivial to blend and concatenate waves together. If this seems up your alley, check out [WAVE PCM soundfile format](https://web.archive.org/web/20080929155546/http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Answer (score 3):

I like [PyAudiere](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaudiere/0.2) , which lets you play numpy arrays as sounds... I guess it jives well with my Matlab background. I believe it's cross-platform.  I think [scikits.audiolab](http://scikits.appspot.com/audiolab) does the same thing, and may be more current / better supported... seems easier to me than trying to save things as wavfiles or write them to buffers and use Python's builtin sound library.

Comment: As far as I can see Audiere can not be downloaded from pypi and their pyaudiere.org site is now some random ad-page.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like all of these sound libraries get abandoned after a few months. It's becoming a real problem. Maybe PyGame is the way to go. It seems like overkill, but at least it's well-supported.

Answer (score 3):

I found these two python repositories very useful, might wanna have a look at it...

**python** https://github.com/JeremyCCHsu/Python-Wrapper-for-World-Vocoder

**ipython** :  https://timsainb.github.io/spectrograms-mfccs-and-inversion-in-python.html

[EDIT] As pointed out, here is an explanational of the two links

**python** one seems to have an error, but many people were able to make it run, so I'm not sure. **ipython**  worked like a charm, so I hope you can run it.

Both of the links are supposed to take an audio as an input, preferably **.wav** file. Featurize it ( USE FFT : 512, step size = 512/8 ) to obtain spectrograms ( you can even visualize it ), it's a 2D matrix, and then train your Machine learning objects or do whatever you want using a matrix that represents the original audio. If you want, at anypoint, what those vectors represent you can resynthesize audio back as well.