# Endless sine tone

Tags: python-3.x, audio

can I play an endless sine tone with python, like this comand on the Linux Bash does it:

```
play -n synth sin 4440  gain 1 vol 1
```

without using subprocess.check_output or os?

Comment: I don't know if this addresses your question, but this question seems to be similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770073/sound-generation-synthesis-with-python

Comment: The problem is that I need an endless sine, wich only stop with an stop command.

Comment: Can you add any context to what you are trying to do? Is there any code you are working with currently?

Comment: No, I haven't developed any code. My Question was, whether there are simple solutions, e.g. an python libary, what can do those things