# Tone generation in Python without freezing the thread?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

Currently I have the following.

```
import winsound


winsound.Beep(1000, 1000)
```

And it works. But it does appear to sleep the thread. In the program I'm developing, sleeping the main thread will be a big no no. I could multi-thread it, but only as a last resort.
Does anyone have any other ways to generate tones on Windows?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How about pyaudio? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770073/sound-generation-synthesis-with-python for example.

Comment: PyAudio isn't seeming to want to install on this system. It errors out with exit status 1 when I install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can beep in another thread as simple as that:

```
import threading
import winsound

threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: winsound.Beep(1000, 1000)
).start()
```